# If she learns the violin, she {get/will get} a job in an orchestra

Tags: word-choice

> If she learns the violin, she {get/will get} a job in an orchestra.

She get or will get and why?

Comment: This sounds like homework. You can look up what is called "the first conditional", though sophisticated linguists don't like that term.

Comment: "Will" is used to talk about what is going to happen in the future (If you are certain of that)

Answer (score 1):

"She get a job" isn't valid for any verb tense; the simple present tense third person would be "she **gets** a job." We *could* use this:

> If she learns the violin, she gets a job...

... but it means the same as "she will get," and is a bit less formal of a usage.

Comment: I disagree that "gets" is equivalent. To me, it implies a guaranteed, non-speculative conditional relationship: the orchestra has promised the violist that if she takes up the violin, they will hire her. It can't be used to make a prediction.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you I agree, it's a promise, but so is "she will." The "she gets" construction isn't a replacement for "she might get," "she can get," etc., anything with any degree of uncertainty. You might argue that there's a difference in that "if she does X she gets Y" connotes an *immediate* reward, while "if she does X she will get Y" might be used for "...after some extra time."

Comment: I really think one needs will get here. However, you could have: If she learns the violin, she gets **the job**.

Comment: @Lambie Good point: I moved straight to abstraction and overlooked the fact that—as a professional violinist myself, I ought to know—no one is guaranteed "a" job, least of all a dime-a-dozen violinist looking for an increasingly-extinct full-time orchestra gig!

Comment: @Lambie Though I am entertained by the idea of an orchestra hiring "on spec" and considering candidates who haven't yet started studying their instrument. :)